# How to pass variable value from job1 to job 2 tags in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

Is it possible to **pass variable value from job1 to job2 tags** in gitlab-ci.yml.

I tried the following

```
job1:
  stage:
   build
  tags:
   [BUILD-POOL]
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_MACHINE=10.15.63.4" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'

job2:
  stage:
   test
  tags:
    - "$BUILD_MACHINE"
  script:
   - echo "job2 test"
  needs:
    - job1
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
```

I am trying this because, in job1 i am using `tags:[BUILD-POOL]` which will select an available free VM.

So i want to build job2 in the same VM where job1 is built.

but for me above mentioned code IP is not assigned to `tags` in job2.

any suggestions/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem will be solved by [sticky runners](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17497), which is an open issue in GitLab.